# Is there any solution to load txt file in to LinearRegression() in Python and calculate average values of predict by mean()?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using pandas to load data from txt file. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
import sklearn.linear_model

wineQuality = pd.read_csv('winequality-all.txt', sep=",")

X = wineQuality.loc[:,("fixed.acidity","volatile.acidity","citric.acid","residual.sugar","chlorides","free.sulfur.dioxide","total.sulfur.dioxide","density","pH","sulphates","alcohol","color")]
y = wineQuality.loc[:,('response')]
X = X.drop(['color'], axis=1)
X = X.to_numpy();
y = y.to_numpy();
print(X)
print(y)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
np.matmul(X,y);
mnk = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print('Score :',mnk.score(X,y))
print('Avg values :',mnk.predict(X.mean().reshape(1, -1)))
```

My winequality-all.txt file looks like this:

```
"fixed.acidity","volatile.acidity","citric.acid","residual.sugar","chlorides","free.sulfur.dioxide","total.sulfur.dioxide","density","pH","sulphates","alcohol","response","color"
7.4,0.7,0,1.9,0.076,11,34,0.9978,3.51,0.56,9.4,3,"red"
7.8,0.88,0,2.6,0.098,25,67,0.9968,3.2,0.68,9.8,3,"red"
7.8,0.76,0.04,2.3,0.092,15,54,0.997,3.26,0.65,9.8,3,"red"
...
```

I was trying to use methods like reshape(-1,1) or (1,-1) on my X and y - didn't work for me.

Output:

- [[ 7.4   0.7   0.   ...  3.51  0.56  9.4 ]  [ 7.8   0.88  0.   ...
  3.2   0.68  9.8 ]  [ 7.8   0.76  0.04 ...  3.26  0.65  9.8 ]  ...  [ 6.5   0.24  0.19 ...  2.99  0.46  9.4 ]  [ 5.5   0.29  0.3  ...  3.34  0.38 12.8 ]  [ 6.    0.21  0.38 ...  3.26  0.32 11.8 ]]
- [3 3 3 ... 4 5 4]
- (5320, 11)
- (5320,)

My error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5320 is different from 11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a numpy array, you need to specify mean with `axis=0` , otherwise it takes the grand mean of the whole array:

```
import sklearn.linear_model

X = np.random.normal(0,1,(20,5))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,20)

mnk = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(mnk.predict(X.mean(axis=0).reshape(1,-1)))
print(np.matmul(mnk.coef_,X.mean(axis=0)) + mnk.intercept_)
```

Otherwise keep it as a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(20,6)),columns=['y','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'])
X = df[['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']]
y = df['y']

mnk = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
mnk.predict(pd.DataFrame(X.mean(axis=0)).T)
```